# Test As Add-on Causes an Error When onOpen Exists

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an add-on for Google Sheets. When the sheet is opened, the script should create a menu item in Add-ons.

The item is added and works when I open the Sheet it's originally bound to. When  trying to test it as an add-on with onOpen as a declared function in my script, it always results in the item not being added and an error being logged in the Google Chrome DevTools console for the Sheet opened for the test:

**Google Apps Script: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and 
try again.**

This error doesn't occur if I comment out the onOpen method.

I've tried running it as an add-on in the following ways with both Auth.none and Auth.limited:

- The original copy of the script attached to its original Sheet.
- The original copy of the script running with a separate Sheet.
- A copy of the script in a separate Google Scripts file running with a different Sheet.
- Creating a new Sheet and bounded script with just an empty onOpen function.

These all result in the error above, and when I uncomment the contents of onOpen functions that do have code, none of their code appears to run.

Here's the original copy's code but keep in mind I still get the error even if the contents are commented out and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) states that even if createMenu is used for an add-on, it's handled correctly by Google App Script:

```
function onOpen(e){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem("Show Sidebar", "showSidebar");
    menu.addToUi();
  } else {
    // Add a new menu (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).

    var topUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    topUI.createMenu("Mail Merge")
        .addItem("Show Sidebar", "showSidebar")
        .addToUi();
  }
}
```

The Logger object also doesn't seem to log my messages while running the script as an add-on.

Comment: In your script, it seems that if ``e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE`` is true, the item is not shown at the menu. Because ``.addToUi()`` is not used. If this was due to the failure of the copy the script, I'm sorry.

Comment: Stop using Logger - embrace Stackdriver. `console.log(....)`

Comment: @Tanaike I did miss the `addToUi()` function and have added it, but I still get the google script error and nothing happens to the menus, for both authentication modes.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question.

Comment: @tehhowch The script is currently in a team drive and there are some administrative restrictions on my organization's Google Cloud Platform. However, the script and sheet will be moved and given to another account I'll have access to soon, to see if the team drive and/or the restrictions are affecting it.

Comment: Apps Scripts, server side code on doesn't log message to the web browser console but the Logger and the execution transcript should work but they are overwritten on each run so it's better to look to the Stackdriver features available either from the Apps Script editor and from the scritpt dashboard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the Sheet over to another account and just having it be owned by that account (not in a team drive) did allow the menu to appear when testing it as an add-on with both types of authorization. The Google App Script error also stopped occurring after doing this.

The most closely related information I could find about Team Drive restrictions was [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#apps_script_cloud_projects_and_team_drives), which says it limits cloud platform interaction. But [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test?utm_campaign=docs-add-ons-415&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog) is Google's page on setting up and running Test As Add-on and it doesn't state anything about the Team Drive or cloud platform.